# How to redirect to URL (with custom headers) from C# Controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt, authorization, request-headers

I need to redirect the user's browser to a new URL from my .NET Core C# controller action, and add my own custom request header with a JWT token.

Is this possible? What's the best way to do this?

Other sites have suggested `Response.Redirect("http://www.whatever.com")` and `Server.Transfer("http://www.whatever.com")`. The former redirects, but I can't get the headers to work. The latter I couldn't get to work at all. `Server` requires `System.Web.HttpContext`, which has been removed from .NET Core.

```
[HttpPost]
public void RedirectWithHeaders(string token)
{
    var payload = decodeJwtFromString(token);
    var jwt = makeNewJwt(payload);

    // Now go to the URL with an authorization header
}
```

This controller action needs to accept a posted string (that part's working fine) and then redirect or otherwise navigate to a new page with an added authorization header (made out of the dissected posted string).

Comment: You cannot make the browser redirect to a URL with any new or altered headers.  Are you redirecting to a URL on the same domain?

Comment: Yes, it's on the same domain.

Answer (score 4):

Add IActionContextAccessor in your Startup.cs

```
 services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Inject it in your controller and Create new RedirectResult :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
   {
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IActionContextAccessor _accessor;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IActionContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _accessor = accessor;
    }

    public IActionResult RedirectTo()
    {
        // Create RedirectResult and add URLHelper 
        var result = new RedirectResult("www.google.com",true);
        result.UrlHelper = new UrlHelper(_accessor.ActionContext); 

        result.UrlHelper
              .ActionContext
              .HttpContext
              .Response.Redirect("www.google.com");

         result.UrlHelper
               .ActionContext
               .HttpContext
               .Response.Headers.Add("Just-Token", new StringValues("JustToken"));
        return result; 
    }

}
```

Response using curl -i cmd :

```
curl -i localhost:5000/Home/redirectTo
    HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
    Date: Thu, 02 Apr 2020 13:09:52 GMT
    Server: Kestrel
    Content-Length: 0
    Location: google.com
    Just-Token: JustToken
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer prematurely.  I kept getting redirected to my own domain, e.g. "https://localhost:1234/Home/redirectTo/www.google.com".  I made this modification and it worked: `var result = new RedirectResult("https://www.google.com", true")`

Comment: I have just use this to add Header to redirect .. not just redirect .

Comment: Works just fine!

Comment: In my opinion, it seems awfully clunky to insert a who new service and rather awkward with this ginormous `.ActionContent.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add` thingy. Undeniably, it works. However, when something gets so complex, it usually a sign that we're working against the technology, instead of with it. I'm not in any way questioning your skills, mate. Just curious if there's a simpler way. Usually, MS forms .NET in a way so that common tasks are made easy. This is, sort of, a common task. Calling it *easy* requires a lot of flexibility in interpretation of the term, though...

Comment: I also noticed an unexpected thing when I was playing with your sample. While the headers are included, just supposed to, the part that would alter the redirection's target and permanency status are not affected. If I use *url1* and *false" in the creation of the object and then try to alter it to *url1* and/or *true* using the injected service, the call executed still leads to the originally set address.

Comment: Yes , in .net if you just when to redirect without  header just use 
 return Redirect("https : //google.com"); and everything gonna work fine .

Comment: in this article you find many other type of redirect . 
https://www.infoworld.com/article/3570787/how-to-redirect-a-request-in-aspnet-core-mvc.html

Comment: just keep in mind that adding a header to a redirected result is not a common task  ... the main reason is that the browser for example don't care if there is another header than location or not ... and will not use them ...

Comment: so when impomented the client gets a 301 response and the response contains the added header. but the new client request to the new url fired from the browser does not contain the added header.

Comment: you need to handle that by yourself , the browser will not do anything with the additional header.